# React Form with file submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am now practicing upload a file by using `Reactjs`. This is a simple problem, but I could not connect the solution to `axios`. I know how the `state` and `Form` works, but my `JavaScript` callback values does not contains any of my given input. Or I could not find my `values`. Here is my case.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import tokamakConfig from './Configuration_icon_by_obsilion.png';
import {Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';

class Advance extends Component {
  handleSubmit(event, values){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(values);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>Please provide necessary information for the operation</h1>
        <img src={tokamakConfig} alt={'tokamak configuration'} />
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group inline>
            <label>Load input file</label>
            <input name={'file'} type='file' />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group inline>
            <label>Comment</label>
            <input name={'comment'} type={'text'} placeholder={'This is an advanced mode'}/>
          </Form.Group>
          <button type={'submit'}>Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Advance;
```

In my `console.log()`. I got `proxy` object and `onSubmit` object. I could not find any of my input there. Then I have no idea how can I dispatch my value to `axios`

**Question:**
How to `POST` file from `form` to `endpoint`

Comment: your content type should be `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: @SangramBadi Thank you for your comment. What should I do? Where do I need to put that argument?

Comment: are you using axios? if yes then you need to pass `Content-Type` there. could you please post your axios code ?

Comment: I knew it. But I am not in that state yet. Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react

Comment: @SangramBadi I have to get the value first. And then dispatch. `axios` I know how to `POST` to backend.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="file" onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e.target.files) } />
```

You need to use onChange event to get the file data.

```
handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList)
    {
        console.log(selectorFiles);
    }
```

Then you need to get the file info inside the method

Comment: Thank you very much! I have never known that I have to use `.bind`. This is a minor question. What kind of the topic I can read on `.bind()` technique?

Comment: you need to check javascript ES6

Comment: Got it. I will enroll in the ES6 class soon.