# How to set MIME type for POST - multipart/form-data in axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to send POST request with MIME - `multipart/form-data`

This is my default configuration for POST headers:
`axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';`

I expect that default `Content-Type` should be `multipart/form-dat`, but in chrome devtools I see `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: To be clear...is that `application/json` in the ***request*** headers and not the ***response*** ones?

Comment: Yes, in the request headers

Comment: try this reference -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react

Comment: It's helps, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const data = new FormData();

data.append('action', 'ADD');
data.append('param', 0);
data.append('secondParam', 0);
data.append('file', new Blob(['test payload'], { type: 'text/csv' }));

axios.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data);
```

This code is using [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Another option is using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');

const form = new FormData();
// Second argument  can take Buffer or Stream (lazily read during the request) too.
// Third argument is filename if you want to simulate a file upload. Otherwise omit.
form.append('field', 'a,b,c', 'blah.csv');
axios.post('http://example.org/endpoint', form, {
  headers: form.getHeaders(),
}).then(result => {
  // Handle result…
  console.log(result.data);
});
```