# React seems to be requiring that Django Model field associated with the variable in React be declared to POST

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I'm fairly new to programming so I am most likely missing something fairly basic but, I have lost a couple day on this issue and can't seem to find a solution. I am following a tutorial from the Great Adib (Source Code: https://github.com/GaziAdib/django_react_fullstack) and I am trying to hook up my React form with my Django backend. I am using axios to handle the API communication and have tested my API using Postman and the Django API UI and it seems to be working just fine, I can even GET data from my Django backend without issues but when I try to POST the data from my form I am running into issues, I keep getting RefrenceErrors on my Django fields that are associated with the according variables in my React code, that it is not defined, here is how I have my code set-up and the error that I am getting:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

[enter image description here][1]const Form = () => {

let history = useHistory();

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")
const [lastInitial, setLastInitial] = useState("")
const [dateVisited, setDateVisited] = useState("")
const [foodRating, setFoodRating] = useState("")
const [serviceRating, setServiceRating] = useState("")
const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

const addReviewForm = async () => {
    let formField = new FormData

    formField.append('firstName', first_name)
    formField.append('lastInitial', first_initial)
    formField.append('dateVisited', date_visited)
    formField.append('foodRating', food_rating)
    formField.append('serviceRating', service_rating)
    formField.append('message', message)

    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/reviewform/',
        data: formField,
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        history.push('/')
    })
}
```

My understanding is that the the Django fields don't need to be declared as the form variables are what will be posted to those variables and from what I can see in the Source Code of the tutorial, they are not declared in any way different from my code.

Would appreciate any help on this, please let me know if any other information is needed.

Code from models.py:

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
contact_form_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
message = models.TextField(max_length=1500, null=False, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

Code from serializers.py:

```
class ContactFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ContactForm
    fields = ('contact_form_id','first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'contact_type', 'message')
```

Code from views.py:

```
class ContactFormView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = ContactFormSerializer
queryset = ContactForm.objects.all()
```

Comment: You can post your django code also here. You can try out axios.post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550834/how-to-set-mime-type-for-post-multipart-form-data-in-axios

Comment: You seem to be using the wrong variable names in all your calls to `formField.append`. The state variable containing the first name is "firstName" but you use "first_name" in formField.append, you're doing this for all of them

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I am not sure I understand, I want axios to append the "first_name" field of my model with the input from the "firstName" variable in my React code. This is how the tutorial I am following along to has theirs set up, except the name of their model field is just "name". My understand is that it should go: formField.append('reactVariable', django_field)