# Node server to send image to cloud to be hosted

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gcloud

I send an image file to my node server via my react app -

I want to host these images on google cloud or similar so they have an accessible URL.

I have tried using cloudinary and google cloud but to no avail thus far!

My react-side code (shortened):

```
imageFile = this.state.files[0])

        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', imageFile);
        sendImage(formData)

    sendImage(image) {
      axios.post("https://137a6167.ngrok.io/image-upload", image, { 
      })
       .then(res => { // then print response status
       console.log(res.statusText)
      })
     }
```

The file is successfully sent to my server and consoled:

```
  app.post('/image-upload', (req, res) => {
  console.log('consoling the req.body!!!!' + JSON.stringify(req.body))
  })
```

THE CONSOLE: consoling the req.body!!!!{"1":"[object File]"}

I did try use this following cloudinary method, yet it threw errors:

```
  cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME, 
  api_key: process.env.API_KEY, 
  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
  })

app.use(formData.parse())

app.post('/image-upload', (req, res) => {

  const values = Object.values(req.files)
  const promises = values.map(image => cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.path))

  Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(results => res.json(results))
})
```

this gave me the error that an unhandled error in the promise wasnt handled and i got a bit lost with where to go beyond that!

I looked at google cloud storage too but couldn't get it working! Any advice?

What I really want to do is return back to my react app the URL of the hosted image - so it can be stored in DB for the user!

If you can help at all that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to fix on the front end before you try to upload to any cloud.

First you need to set `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` header in `axios` to send the file data properly.

Check this thread for more details: [How do I set multipart in axios with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react)

Then on the express side you need `multer` or some other similar library to receive the data. You can't access it from `req.body`. `multer` adds `req.files` for example.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Try there steps and then post the exact error message you are receiving from google cloud.