# How can I post file and data together via Axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to post data (in a Vue application). There is also an image file input in the form. All tutorials and answers are just telling to send the file alone or with other files.[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096508/2549621)[[2]](https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/)

What I want to do is to append the file to the existing object that I create with v-model bindings.

```
// Vue

<template>
    <input name="title" type="text" v-model="newPost.title" />
    <textarea name="content" v-model="newPost.content"></textarea>
    <input name="image" type="file" />
</template>
<script>
    ...
    newPost: {
        title: null,
        image: null,
        content: null
    }
    ...
    addNewPost() {
        axios.post('/api/posts', this.newPost)
    }
</script>
```

How should I do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Well, I validate form inputs in the newPost object on the server-side. Appending each input to a FormData variable (let's say newPostData) is breaking the form validation. FormData doesn't support appending objects AFAIK (see https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/92).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Base64 encode in client side and add the encoded string to your post request and decode from server side:
image here will be the encoded string an you can send axios request as you wrote.

Comment: I'll give it a try ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount the selected file with *v-model*. Since the file is a constantly changing element, you should use the **@change** and **ref** attribute.

```
<input name="image" type="file" @change="selectedPostImage" ref="postImage"/>
```

The following operation is performed in the function that captures the selected file.

```
selectedPostImage(){
   this.newPost.image= this.$refs.postImage.files[0]
}
```

After these steps, you can send data with axios. Good codings..