# how to send files and data with axios in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

backend is expecting something like

```
    {
       "key" : "xyz"
}// and two files
```

I've tried the following code, but it always shows empty params passed in url

```
 const obj = {
        key : [this.state.key]
      };
      const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
      const blob = new Blob([json], {
        type: 'application/json'
      });
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("params", blob);
      data.append("data1",this.state.file1)
      data.append("data2",this.state.file2)
      
        let res= await axios.get(url,data);
        console.log(res)
```

Comment: Another source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data

Comment: you can find another source with a complete react example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878838/how-do-i-set-multipart-in-axios-with-react

Answer (score 0):

You can't send data(body) by using get method. I think you need to use post method.

```js
 const obj = {
        key : [this.state.key]
      };
      const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
      const blob = new Blob([json], {
      type: 'application/json'
      });
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("params", blob);
      data.append("data1",this.state.file1)
      data.append("data2",this.state.file2)
      
      let res= await axios.post(url,data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use formData with get, in order to send with body, file upload has to be a post request.

```
let res= await axios.post(url,data);
```