# Axios post formdata not working properly in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data

I need to send an image and some details as form-data in react-native

For that, I'm using `axios` post method.

Here is my code:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('taskId', taskId);
formData.append('taskName', taskName);
formData.append('projectId', projectId);
formData.append('projectName', projectName);
formData.append('media', media);

const res = await Axios.post(`${URL}`, formData, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
});
```

My server is getting media files as empty.. can anyone know what am I doing wrong here!?

Here is my request header:
[image: My request header]

PS: **I. have tested on postman and its working fine over their**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41986940/8437974 Is this helpful in your case?

Comment: What type of `media` is?

Comment: @l_bug its a images which picking from gallery.it contain type name and uri

Comment: How are you receiving the request on the `server-side`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was with media type the library I used to choose media was giving media type of `image/jpg` if I select png or jpg or jpeg. so I upadted my code like this

```
 mediaData.forEach((item: any, index: number) => {
     formData.append(`media`, {
          uri: item?.uri,
          type: item?.type === 'image/jpg' ? 'image/jpeg' : item?.type,
          name: item?.fileName,
     });
 });
```

After updating like this everything works fine

Answer (score 5):

I believe the issue is that you're trying to send `media` as a json object. There are two ways to solve this.

**1. Stringify the media before submitting it**

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('media', JSON.stringify(media));
```

You may also need to make necessary changes to your backend to handle this.

**2. Split the media object into separate fields**

You mentioned that the `media` object has a name and file, so you can do something like this.

```js
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('mediaName', media.name);
    formData.append('media', media.file);
```

Note that in the second example, I am assuming the properties of the `media` object.

I think for your use case, some variation of the second solution is preferred as it is already working on postman.

Answer (score 1):

When sending Image to Backend you have to Send Type along with image
Try this

```
var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('profile_image', {
    uri: media,
    name: "mediaName",
    type: mimeType
});
```

Comment: Yeah my issue was related with the image type `'image/jpg'` is not uploading and when i replaced that with `'image/jpeg'` it worked fine